# Updating value in a dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary of type `[String:Any]()` and a value is being added to it like so...

```
myDictionary["qty"] = "1"
```

Now `qty` is the quantity which I can change from a picker view. So if I select a value of 3 from the pickerview, the updated quantity will be 3 now instead of 1. That I'm trying to achieve like so...

```
 myDictionary.updateValue(cell.qtyPickerField.text!, forKey: "qty")

 arrayOfDictionary.append(myDictionary)
```

But here, since I'm using append, one more dictionary is added to the array with the quantity value as 3. But what I want to achieve is to update the the dictionary I'm already having with the value of 3 instead of 1 and not add one more dictionary as I'm doing now.

But how that can be achieved that I'm not able to figure out...

**EDIT** . The code in picker view didSelectRow is as below...

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView is MyPickerView {

            if let cell = (pickerView as! MyPickerView).cell {

        cell.qtyPickerField.text = noOfItems[row] // for displaying of nos picker view


  myDictionary.updateValue(cell.qtyPickerField.text!, forKey: "qty")

 arrayOfDictionary.append(self.appDelegate.myDictionary)

        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOfDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
                print(data)
        self.appDelegate.jsonValue = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
        print(self.appDelegate.jsonValue)


                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: you have not mentioned where is that arrayOfDictionary and why is this even there. What is that?

Comment: the `arrayOfDictionary ` is in the pickerview `didSelectRow`...

Comment: and it is declared like so...`var arrayOfDictionary = [[String:Any]]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the dictionary from `arrayOfDictionary`:

```
let index : Int = // index for myDictionary
myDictionary = arrayOfDictionary[index]
```

then

```
myDictionary["qty"] = cell.qtyPickerField.text!
arrayOfDictionary[index] = myDictionary
```

Comment: instead of this part...`arrayOfDictionary.append(myDictionary)` ... ?

Comment: You don't need to append the dictionary to anything. Can you post didSelectRow code as well please?

Comment: First you need to get the dictionary from array or at least know its index in array then you can modify it the same way.

Comment: So you mean the answer will be something like this...`myDictionary.updateValue(cell.qtyPickerField.text!, forKey: "qty")

myDictionary["qty"] = cell.qtyPickerField.text!
`

Comment: If myDictionary is already in array then you don't need to reassign it. Remove the append line. Just try my answer, and let me know if it works

Comment: I tried with just your line of code and also added this line of code `myDictionary.updateValue(cell.qtyPickerField.text!, forKey: "qty")
` along with your line of code. But in both cases it didn't work....

Comment: I did try what u suggested, @ Umair M. But the issue is everytime the value of index is 0. So if I have 2 dictionaries, only the first one is always updated.

Comment: As you have more than one dictionaries, you have to choose which one you want to modify/update. This solely depends on your business logic.

Comment: Basically I have tableview cells loaded in a tableview and each of those cells have a picker textfield..and each of those cells correspond to the index in which the dictionaries can be shown...

Comment: To access the indexpath if this is done `let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPath(for: cell)
if let index = indexPath {}`then it throws the error ` Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'IndexPath'`

Comment: you can only use Int value as array index. try to get Int value for example indexPath.row

Answer (score -3):

The Array/Dictionary in swift is value type and what you want is act dictionary as reference type. In your case use `NSMutableDictionary` e.g.

```
let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
var array = [NSMutableDictionary]()
dict["qty"] = "1"
array.append(dict)
print("Array has:\(array)")
print("------ Now we'll change the data withoout appending -----")
dict["qty"] = "3"
print("Array has:\(array)")
```

**Console logs:**

```
Array has:[{
    qty = 1;
}]
------ Now we'll change the data withoout appending -----
Array has:[{
    qty = 3;
}]
```

Comment: As you can see in my example after appending I've printed the value and then updated the dictionary and then I din't appended it

Comment: Negative voters I'll appreciate if you guys can point me what's wrong in the answer

Comment: use `[String: Any]` instead of `NSMutableDictionary` you should be upto date.